# Get the count of account by same phone number using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class, before-trigger

I have written one trigger on account object.It will check the phone number from account and will search on custom object(phone_Details__c).If found then it will update the Account Name in Phone details.
and also needs the count of how many account are with same phone number in Phone_Details__c.

Please suggest the solution..

```
public static void PhoneDetails(list<account>accList){
    Map<string,account> phoneNum=new Map<string,account>();
    for(account acc:acclist){
        phoneNum.put(acc.phone,acc);
    }
    list<account>acname=new list<account>([select id from account where phone in :phonenum.keySet()]);
    map<id,phone_Details__c> Phdetails=new Map<id,phone_Details__c>([select id,Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c,Name,Account_Name__c from phone_Details__c where name in:phoneNum.keyset()]);       
    list<phone_Details__c>phList=new list<phone_Details__c>();
    for(phone_Details__c ph:phdetails.values()){
        if(phoneNum.containskey(ph.name)){       
            account acc=phonenum.get(ph.name);
            ph.Account_Name__c  =acc.Name;
            ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c=count;
            phList.add(ph);
        }
    }
    update phList;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
public static void PhoneDetails(List<Account> accList){
     Map<string, List<Account>> phoneNumMap = new Map<string, List<Account>>();
     for(Account acc :acclist){
          if(phoneNumMap.containskey(acc.phone)){
               phoneNumMap.get(acc.phone).add(acc);
          }
          else{
               phoneNumMap.put(acc.phone, new List<Account>{acc});
          }
     }

     List<phone_Details__c> phList = new List<phone_Details__c>();
     for(Phone_Details__c ph : [SELECT Id, Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c, Account_Name__c FROM Phone_Details__c WHERE name IN :phoneNumMap.keyset()]){
          if(phoneNumMap.containskey(ph.name)){       
               List<Account> acc = phonenum.get(ph.name);
               ph.Account_Name__c  = acc[0].Name; //There may be number of accounts having same phone number. Choose which account name should be here.
               ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c = ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c + phoneNumMap.get(ph.name).size();
               phList.add(ph);
          }
     }
     UPDATE phList;      
}
```

Comment: I am getting error in this line    Account[] acc = phonenum.get(ph.name);

Comment: **Illegal assignment from List<Account> to Account**

Comment: @aditi Try the updated code

Comment: Its running but count is showing as 1 always,even i have existing 4 acount with same phone number

Comment: Whwnever I am editing account it is increasing count by 1 everytime.Suppose i am having same phone number for 4 account then if i edited one account and save it ,its increasing the count of total number of account to 1.

Comment: @aditi You may need set a checkbox in account to check if its already counted or not. Set this checkbox to true whenever you count the number of account.

Answer (score 0):

@aditi Replace

```
ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c=ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c!=null ? ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c+1 : 1;
```

instead

```
ph.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c = h.Number_Of_Account_with_same_number__c + phoneNumMap.get(ph.name).size();
```